# Tic Tac Toe with Random coin flip

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Homework problem from class: I have to generate a tic tac toe game which uses a coin toss to determine who goes first. I've generated most of my code, but there are still several things/bugs I can't figure out.

1. I know how to do the coin flip. But, how do I get the program to choose who goes first.
2. Winning square or Game-ending square doesn't get X or O on it.
3. There is no message for a Tie game.
4. There is no message when you just press enter without entering any value.

   ```
   #include "pch.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <time.h>


   using namespace std;

   void Flip_Coin();
   void Do_Exercise();
   void Display_Board();
   void Ask_Turn();
   char Check_Winner();
   void Computer_Player_Turn();

   char Board[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

   int n = 0;

   int main()
   {
       srand(time(0));

       Do_Exercise();

       cin.get();

       return 0;
   }

   void Do_Exercise()
   {
       Flip_Coin();
       while (true)
       {
           n++;
           Display_Board();
           Ask_Turn();
           if (Check_Winner() == 'X')
           {
               cout << "Human Wins!" << endl;
               break;
           }
           else if (Check_Winner() == 'O')
           {
               cout << "Computer Wins!" << endl;
               break;
           }
           else if (Check_Winner() == 'T' && n == 9)
           {

               cout << "It's a draw." << endl;
               break;
           }
           Computer_Player_Turn();
           if (Check_Winner() == 'X')
           {
               cout << "Human Wins!" << endl;
               break;
           }
           else if (Check_Winner() == 'O')
           {
               cout << "Computer Wins!" << endl;
               break;
           }
           else if (Check_Winner() == 'T' && n == 9)
           {

               cout << "It's a draw." << endl;
               break;
           }
       }
   }

   void Flip_Coin()
   {
       int Flip;

       cout << "Welcome to Tic - Tac - toe.\n\n"
           << "Wait I am flipping a coin to see who goes first . . .\n\n";

       Flip = rand() % 2;

       if (Flip == 0)
       {
           cout << "Computer wins coin toss.\n\n";
       }
       else
       {
           cout << "Human wins coin toss.\n\n";
       }
       cout << "The board is laid out like this:\n\n";
   }

   void Display_Board()
   {
       for (int Row = 0; Row < 3; Row++)
       {
           for (int Column = 0; Column < 3; Column++)
           {
               cout << Board[Row][Column] << "\t";
           }
           cout << "\n\n";
       }
   }

   void Ask_Turn()
   {
       string input;

       while (true)
       {
           cout << "Enter the position to place your X: ";
           cin >> input;
           cout << endl;

           if (input != "")
           {
               char entered = input.c_str()[0]; // sets char character to act in place of string

               if (entered >= '1' && entered <= '9')
               {
                   cout << "The human places a X-token at position: " << entered << "\n\n";
                   cout << "Current board:\n\n";
                   int entered_number = entered - '0'; // changes char to int form
                   int index = entered_number - 1;

                   int row = index / 3;
                   int col = index % 3;

                   char grid_position = Board[row][col];

                   if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O')
                   {
                       cout << "That position is already taken. ";
                   }
                   else {
                       Board[row][col] = 'X';
                       break;
                   }
               }
               else {
                   cout << "You must entered in the the range of 1-9.\n";
               }
           }
           else {
               cout << "You must enter something!"; // doesnt work
           }
       }
   }

   char Check_Winner()
   {
       //first player
       if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[0][1] == 'X' && Board[0][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';
       if (Board[1][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[1][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';
       if (Board[2][0] == 'X' && Board[2][1] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';

       if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[1][0] == 'X' && Board[2][0] == 'X')
           return 'X';
       if (Board[0][1] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[2][1] == 'X')
           return 'X';
       if (Board[0][2] == 'X' && Board[1][2] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';

       if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';
       if (Board[2][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[0][2] == 'X')
           return 'X';

       //second player
       if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[0][1] == 'O' && Board[0][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';
       if (Board[1][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';
       if (Board[2][0] == 'O' && Board[2][1] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';

       if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[1][0] == 'O' && Board[2][0] == 'O')
           return 'O';
       if (Board[0][1] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[2][1] == 'O')
           return 'O';
       if (Board[0][2] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';

       if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';
       if (Board[2][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[0][2] == 'O')
           return 'O';

       return 'T';
   }

   void Computer_Player_Turn()
   {
       while (true)
       {
           int computer_choice = (rand() % 9) + 1;

           int row = (computer_choice - 1) / 3;
           int col = (computer_choice - 1) % 3;

           char grid_position = Board[row][col];

           if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else {
               cout << "The Computer places a O-token at position: " << computer_choice << "\n\n";
               Board[row][col] = 'O';
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1) right now you have hardcoded to call `Ask_Turn` first and then call `Computer_Player_Turn`. instead of calling them in this way, call them first from coin flip and then let the two functions call each other.
3) change the n==9 to n==8 in two lines that have `Check_Winner() == 'T'`
4) Ask for the input in a while loop, and as long as the input is empty be in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

1) Right now you have hard-coded to call `Ask_Turn` first and then call `Computer_Player_Turn`. Instead of calling them in this way, call them first from coin flip and then let the two functions call each other when they finish.

2) Call `Display_Board()` before checking for winner.

3) Fixed here. You were only adding n by 1 for every 2 turns.

4) Ask for the input in a while loop, and as long as the input is empty be in the loop

So making all those changes, the code should look something similar to below.

I have tested the code here, https://onlinegdb.com/S1Qdcr63X

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

void Flip_Coin();
void Do_Exercise();
void Display_Board();
void Ask_Turn();
char Check_Winner();
void Computer_Player_Turn();

char Board[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

int n = 0;

void Computer_Player_Turn();
void Ask_Turn();

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    Do_Exercise();

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void Do_Exercise()
{
    Flip_Coin();
}

void Flip_Coin()
{
    int Flip;

    cout << "Welcome to Tic - Tac - toe.\n\n"
        << "Wait I am flipping a coin to see who goes first . . .\n\n";

    Flip = rand() % 2;

    if (Flip == 0)
    {
        cout << "Computer wins coin toss.\n\n";
        Computer_Player_Turn();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Human wins coin toss.\n\n";
        Ask_Turn();
    }
}

void Display_Board()
{
    for (int Row = 0; Row < 3; Row++)
    {
        for (int Column = 0; Column < 3; Column++)
        {
            cout << Board[Row][Column] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}


char Check_Winner()
{
    //first player
    if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[0][1] == 'X' && Board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (Board[1][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (Board[2][0] == 'X' && Board[2][1] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[1][0] == 'X' && Board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (Board[0][1] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (Board[0][2] == 'X' && Board[1][2] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (Board[0][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (Board[2][0] == 'X' && Board[1][1] == 'X' && Board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    //second player
    if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[0][1] == 'O' && Board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (Board[1][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (Board[2][0] == 'O' && Board[2][1] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[1][0] == 'O' && Board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (Board[0][1] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (Board[0][2] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (Board[0][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (Board[2][0] == 'O' && Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    return 'T';
}

bool winner()
{
    if (Check_Winner() == 'X')
    {
        cout << "Human Wins!" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if (Check_Winner() == 'O')
    {
        cout << "Computer Wins!" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if (Check_Winner() == 'T' && n == 9)
    {

        cout << "It's a draw." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Ask_Turn()
{
    n++;

    string input = "";

    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the position to place your X: ";
            cin >> input;
            cout << endl;
        }
        while(input == ""  || (input.c_str()[0] < '1' || input.c_str()[0] > '9'));


        char entered = input.c_str()[0]; // sets char character to act in place of string

        cout << "The human places a X-token at position: " << entered << "\n\n";
        cout << "Current board:\n\n";
        int entered_number = entered - '0'; // changes char to int form
        int index = entered_number - 1;

        int row = index / 3;
        int col = index % 3;

        char grid_position = Board[row][col];

        if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O')
        {
            cout << "That position is already taken. ";
            n--;
            Ask_Turn();
        }
        else {
            Board[row][col] = 'X';
            break;
        }
    }


    Display_Board();

    if(winner())
        return;
    else
     Computer_Player_Turn();
}

void Computer_Player_Turn()
{
    n++;
    while (true)
    {
        int computer_choice = (rand() % 9) + 1;

        int row = (computer_choice - 1) / 3;
        int col = (computer_choice - 1) % 3;

        char grid_position = Board[row][col];

        if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Computer places a O-token at position: " << computer_choice << "\n\n";
            Board[row][col] = 'O';
            break;
        }
    }

    Display_Board();

    if(winner())
        return;
    else
        Ask_Turn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Answered all my questions.  I just got rid of the condition:  if (input != "") and  else (cout << "You must entered in the the range of 1-9), since the program just continues to await an input if I press enter without inputting anything.

Comment: @Fummy I have edited the code and removed two `if` statements from `Ask_Turn` as both the conditions are already being checked by the do while loop.

Comment: Tyty, but the tie condition was not returning a full display of Xs and Os. Changing the condition (Check_Winner() == 'T' && n == 8) back to n==9 solved the issue. Your solution of calling Display_Board() before checking for winner already fixed those bugs. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. That's because `n=1` before the first move so it should end with 9.

Comment: @Fummy, if this solution worked for you, accept this as answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: sorry, still new to stack overflow